# Different alignment of ::after pseudo element in a flex-box in Safari

Tags: css

While implementing a simple toggle control I encountered a problem that only seems to appear in Safari. The same code works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

```css
.mgs.huge {
font-size: 36pt;  
}

input.mgs.toggle {
display: none;
}

label.mgs.toggle {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;

width: max-content;
position: relative;

--toggle-color: 49, 112, 212;
}

/* The toggle background. */
label.mgs.toggle::before {
display: inline-block;
content: "";
height: 12px;
width: 23px;

border: 1px solid rgba(var(--toggle-color), 1);
background-color: rgba(var(--toggle-color), 0.75);
border-radius: 25pt;
margin-right: 4px;
}

label.mgs.toggle.huge::before {
height: 35px;
width: 69px;
}

/* The circle (handle) in the toggle - unchecked, standard size. */
label.mgs.toggle::after {
flex: 0 0 auto;
align-self: center;
content: "";

position: absolute;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
left: 1px;

background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
transition: left 0.2s;
}

label.mgs.toggle.huge::after {
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}

input:checked.mgs.toggle.huge + label::after  {
left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="mgs toggle huge" readonly="" id="toggle6" value="">
<label for="toggle6" class="mgs toggle huge">Huge</label>
```

In Safari the white knob doesn't align vertically. By specifying a top value you can align it manually (in this case by adding 11px top to `label.mgs.toggle.huge::after`), but unfortunately this shows another problem: Firefox doesn't use the same vertical offset as Chrome and Safari do: the circle is offset subtly by half a pixel or so.

Hence I would prefer a solution where Safari does the automatic vertical centering, as it is supposed in this flex-box layout.

Here's also a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/3Ltkwaux/.

Comment: Which version of Firefox do you test on?

Comment: Version 74 here.